# Java/Scala BigInteger Pasting

Tags: java, scala, biginteger, bigint

I have a problem with the Java `BigInteger` class: I can't paste a large value into `BigInteger`. For example, let's say I want to assign a `BigInteger` to this number:

```
26525285981219105863630848482795
```

I cannot assign it directly, because the compiler thinks it's an integer:

```scala
val bi = 26525285981219105863630848482795 //compile error
```

But I want it to be a `BigInteger`. Is there any way to be able to directly paste this into the source code?

If there is no such way, then is there a way in Scala, which has a much easier to use `BigInt` class?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the compiler thinks it's an integer"*. How can the compiler think a 30-digit number is an `Integer`?

Comment: @oxbow - I think Michael meant that the Scala compiler thinks that the literal is an integer and then complains that "integer number too large". Try `val a = 26525285981219105863630848482795` in the Scala interpreter :).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

rtperson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689414/java-scala-biginteger-pasting/1689436#1689436) is correct from a Java perspective, but in Scala you can do more with `scala.BigInt`s than what you can do with `java.math.BigInteger`s.

For example:

```
scala> val a = new BigInteger("26525285981219105863630848482795");
a: java.math.BigInteger = 26525285981219105863630848482795

scala> a + a
:7: error: type mismatch;
found   : java.math.BigInteger
required: String
       a + a
```

The canonical way in Scala to instantiate a class is to use a factory located in the
[companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/BigInt%24object.html). When you write Foo(args) in Scala, this is translated to Foo.apply(args), where Foo is a singleton object - the companion object. So to find the ways of constructing `BigInt`s you could have a look at the `BigInt` object in the Scala library, and specifically at its `apply` construct.

So, three ways of constructing an `BigInt` are: passing it an `Int`, a `Long` or a `String` to parse. Example:

```
scala> val x = BigInt(12)
x: BigInt = 12

scala> val y = BigInt(12331453151315353L)
y: BigInt = 12331453151315353

scala> val z = BigInt("12124120474210912741099712094127124112432")
z: BigInt = 12124120474210912741099712094127124112432

scala> x + y * z
res1: BigInt = 149508023628635151923723925873960750738836935643459768508
```

Note the nice thing that you can do natural looking arithmetic operations with a `BigInt`, which is not possible with a `BigInteger` !

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("26525285981219105863630848482795");
```

BigInteger reads strings and parses them into the correct number. Because of this, you'll want to check out java.text.NumberFormat.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Scala 3`, and improvements brought to [numeric literals](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/numeric-literals.html), you can use the following form:

```
val big: BigInt = 26525285981219105863630848482795
// 26525285981219105863630848482795
```

or even:

```
val big: BigInt = 26_525_285_981_219_105_863_630_848_482_795
// 26525285981219105863630848482795
```